# Transposing 8XB Bits

Tags: java

I am trying to transpose 8X8 bit array. Transpose(A) is working but Transpose(Transpose(A) is not working for certain examples. I know there is something need to be done with signed bytes. But not sure how to do this. Below is the code which is not working on some examples. Can somebody help me?

```
  public class  BitTranspose
  { 
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    byte A[] =new byte[]{'S','U','D','H','A','K','A','R'};

    System.err.println("\nPrinting A. A holds the letters SUDHAKAR");
    print(A);
    byte B[]=new byte[A.length];
    System.err.println("\nTransposing A..");
    transpose(A,1,1,B);
    print(B); // O.K        
    A=new byte[B.length];
    System.err.println("\nTransposing B..");
    transpose(B,1,1,A); 
    print(A); // Not O.K

}
public static void print(byte[] A)
{
    System.err.println();
    for(int i=0;i<A.length;i++)
    {
        System.err.println(toBinary(A[i]));
    }
}

public static String toBinary(byte b)   
    {
    String sb=new String();
    for (int i=7; i>=0; i--)
    {
         sb=sb+((b >> i)&1);
    }
    return sb;
}
static void transpose(byte A[], int m, int n, byte B[]) 
    {
       int x, y, t;          

        x = (A[0]<<24)   | (A[m]<<16)   | (A[2*m]<<8) | A[3*m]; 
        y = (A[4*m]<<24) | (A[5*m]<<16) | (A[6*m]<<8) | A[7*m]; 
        t = (x ^ (x >> 7)) & 0x00AA00AA;x = x ^ t ^ (t << 7); 
        t = (y ^ (y >> 7)) & 0x00AA00AA;y = y ^ t ^ (t << 7); 

        t = (x ^ (x >>14)) & 0x0000CCCC;x = x ^ t ^ (t <<14); 
        t = (y ^ (y >>14)) & 0x0000CCCC;y = y ^ t ^ (t <<14); 

        t = (x & 0xF0F0F0F0) | ((y >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F); 
        y = ((x << 4) & 0xF0F0F0F0) | (y & 0x0F0F0F0F); 
                    x = t;       
        B[0]=(byte)(x>>24);  B[n]=(byte)(x>>16);  B[2*n]=(byte)(x>>8);  B[3*n]=(byte)(x); 
        B[4*n]=(byte)(y>>24);B[5*n]=(byte)(y>>16);B[6*n]=(byte)(y>>8);  B[7*n]=(byte)(y); 
} }
```

And below is the output

`Printing A. A Holds the letters SUDHAKAR



01010011

01010101

01000100

01001000

01000001

01001011

01000001

01010010



Transposing A..



00000000

11111111

00000000

11000001

00010100

01100000

10000101

11001110



Transposing B..



11111111

11111111

11101110

11101110

11101111

11101111

11101111

11111110`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably in these two lines

```
x = (A[0]<<24)   | (A[m]<<16)   | (A[2*m]<<8) | A[3*m];
y = (A[4*m]<<24) | (A[5*m]<<16) | (A[6*m]<<8) | A[7*m];
```

Because in `(A[m]<<16)`, `A[m]` is first sign-extended and then shifted. That destroys the upper bits if `A[m]` is negative (ie unsigned bigger than 127).

Try changing them to

```
x = (A[0]<<24)   | ((A[m]&0xFF)<<16)   | ((A[2*m] & 0xFF)<<8) | (A[3*m] & 0xFF);
y = (A[4*m]<<24) | ((A[5*m]&0xFF)<<16) | ((A[6*m] & 0xFF)<<8) | (A[7*m] & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Got it my friend, thank you for the correction you have suggested.